# S3 Ruby Client - when to specify regional endpoint

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have buckets in 2 AWS regions.  I'm able to perform puts or gets against both buckets without specifying the regional endpoint(the ruby client defaults to us-east-1).

I haven't found much relevant info on how requests on a bucket reach the proper regional endpoint when the region is not specified.  From what I've found(https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/223#issuecomment-22872906), it appears that requests are routed to the bucket's proper region via DNS.

Does specifying the region have any advantages when performing puts and gets against existing buckets?  I'm trying to decide whether I need to specify the appropriate region for operations against a bucket or if I can just rely on it working.

Note that the buckets are long lived so the DNS propagation delays mentioned in the linked github issue are not an issue.

SDK docs for region:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Core/Configuration.html#region-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is any performance benefit to putting/getting data if you specify the bucket.  All bucket names are supposed to be unique across all regions.  I don't think there's a lot of overhead in that lookup, compared to data throughput.

I welcome comments to the contrary.